# PHP - Get value from xml file

Tags: php, xml

Using the following xml: http://www.bnr.ro/nbrfxrates.xml

How can I get the EUR value?

Been trying like this ... but no luck.

```
            $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
            $xmlDoc->load('http://www.bnr.ro/nbrfxrates.xml');

            $searchNode = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName("Cube");

            var_dump($searchNode);

            foreach ($searchNode as $searchNode) {
                $valueID = $searchNode->getAttribute('Rate');

                echo $valueID;

            }
```

Comment: `Cube` tag hasn't `Rate` attribute. Do you mean `date` attribute or `Rate` child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this

```
<?php
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load('http://www.bnr.ro/nbrfxrates.xml');


foreach ($xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('Rate') as $searchNode) {
    if($searchNode->getAttribute('currency') === 'EUR') {
        echo $searchNode->nodeValue;
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First `Rate` is not an attribute but an element. So you would need another `getElementsByTagName('Rate')` and loop over it. However the XML uses a default namespace so `getElementByTagNameNS('http://www.bnr.ro/xsd', 'Rate')` would be the correct way.

An easier way is to use Xpath to fetch the value directly:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->load('http://www.bnr.ro/nbrfxrates.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$xpath->registerNamespace('r', 'http://www.bnr.ro/xsd');

var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate('number(//r:Cube/r:Rate[@currency="EUR"])')
);
```

Output:

```
float(4.4961)
```

Xpath does not have a default namespace, so you have to register your own alias for it (I used `r` in the example.).

#### The Xpath expression

- fetch any `{http://www.bnr.ro/nbrfxrates.xml}Cube`
  `//r:Cube`
- fetch all `{http://www.bnr.ro/nbrfxrates.xml}Rate` children
  `//r:Cube/r:Rate`
- filter by the `currency` attribute
  `//r:Cube/r:Rate[@currency="EUR"]`
- cast the first found node into a number
  `number(//r:Cube/r:Rate[@currency="EUR"])`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I ll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
    $xmlDoc->load('http://www.bnr.ro/nbrfxrates.xml');

    foreach($xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName("Rate")  as $node)
    {
        $currency = $node->getAttribute('currency');
        if($currency == 'EUR')
        {
             $value = $node->nodeValue;
        }
    }
    echo 'value for EUR is - '. $value;

?>
```